# Two variables integrals: How to integrate with respect to one variable, then evaluate and plot the result with respect to the second variable? PART 2

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, evaluation

I have got a very usefull answer to my problem yesterday. Now, I wish to improve the code, including a new variable in other to obtain a 3D-plot. Here is the sample i wrote already. Please check any error and propose strategies to improve, because it keeps running indefinitely with not result yet on my computer.

```
    ClearAll[T, z, Pr, D1, D2, XX];
x = 10^-4; y = 10^4; n2 = 2; alpha = 2;
W1 = Sqrt[n2^2 - z^2];
W2 = Sqrt[z^2 - n2^2];
Pr = ((alpha - 1) (x y)^(alpha - 1))/(y^(alpha - 1) - x^(alpha - 1));
D1[T_, p_] := Pr*p*Exp[(-z)*T]*(Cos[T*W1]/z^2 + (1/(z*W1))*Sin[T*W1]);
D2[T_, p_] := Pr*Exp[-z T] (p*Cosh[T W2]/z^2 + 1/(z W2) Sinh[T W2]);
XX[T_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[D1[T, p], {z, x, n2}] + NIntegrate[D2[T, p], {z, n2, y}];

Plot3D[XX[T, p], {T, 0, 10}, {p, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"T", "p", "XX(T)"}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: What happens when you use a discrete step-size in your plotting? You’ll likely have to assemble the data in a table and use `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: Understood. But i am not yet very familiar with the software. Can you please help me with a sample of what you want me to try??

Comment: I show you an easier (read: lazier) way in the answer I just posted. I did this on mobile so I apologize for the rough image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` for fast plot.

```
Plot3D[XX[T, p], {T, 0, 10}, {p, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"T", "p", "XX(T)"}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Otherwise, you can use `ListPlot3D`.

This takes about 30 seconds on my PC

```
data = Table[{T, p, XX[T, p]}, {T, 0, 10, .1}, {p, 0, 1, .1}];
ListPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice! I didn’t consider this. I figured there might be some issue with wolfram’s automated optimizations when it comes to plotting “symbolically”, by which I mean without specifying discrete step-sizes. This is likely managed using the `PerformanceGoal`, cool! Check out my abuse of `DiscretePlot3D`, I wonder what you think of that? :D

Comment: @CATrevillian I have not used `DiscretePlot3D` before. Nice find.

Comment: Thanks, Nasser! This is my first time using it, too. Though it needs a bit of tweaking to work like `ListPlot3D` does with a `List` of data, I’m very glad to have found it, and once I’m on my PC in the morning, I’ll see how the speed compares.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm on it

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to build a `Table`, then use something like `ListPlot3D`. However, there exists `DiscretePlot3D`, so, let’s use this:

```
DiscretePlot3D[XX[T, p],
{T, 0, 10.,10./50},
{p, 0, 1.,1./50},
AxesLabel -> {"T", "p", "XX(T)"},
Joined->True,
ExtentSize->None,
Filling->None]
```

Which gives us this:
[image: OP’s requested plot using DiscretePlot3D]

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up `NIntegrate` for plotting:

```
opts /; MemberQ[Stack[], Plot3D] = { (* don't need high prec for plot *)
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive",
     "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0,
     Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 11}},
   PrecisionGoal -> 4,
   AccuracyGoal -> 5,
   MaxRecursion -> 0};
opts /; True = {}; (* use defaults outside of Plot3D *)

XX[T_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[D1[T, p], {z, x, n2}, Evaluate@opts] + 
  NIntegrate[D2[T, p], {z, n2, y}, Evaluate@opts];

Plot3D[XX[T, p], {T, 0, 10}, {p, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"T", "p", "XX(T)"}, PlotPoints -> {45, 9}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

It's a little faster (not sure why) if you don't worry about the complex numbers in `D1[]`, which come out real anyway:

```
XX[T_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[D1[T, p], {z, x, n2, y}, Evaluate@opts];

Plot3D[XX[T, p], {T, 0, 10}, {p, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"T", "p", "XX(T)"}, PlotPoints -> {45, 9}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

This is about twice as fast or more than just using `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`:

```
XX[T_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[D1[T, p], {z, x, n2}] + NIntegrate[D2[T, p], {z, n2, y}];
Plot3D[XX[T, p], {T, 0, 10}, {p, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"T", "p", "XX(T)"}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Much faster than `DiscretePlot3D`:

```
DiscretePlot3D[XX[T, p], {T, 0, 10., 10./50}, {p, 0, 1., 1./50}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"T", "p", "XX(T)"}, Joined -> True, 
  ExtentSize -> None, Filling -> None] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]