# How to implement meshing in DiscretePlot3D?

Tags: plotting, mesh

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216440/63039) I show a method to use [`DiscretePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot3D.html) to plot a numerical function which requires a discrete step-size to be plotted, making `DiscretePlot3D` the perfect tool for the job. The code:

```
DiscretePlot3D[XX[T, p],
{T, 0, 10.,10./50},
{p, 0, 1.,1./50},
AxesLabel -> {"T", "p", "XX(T)"},
Joined->True,
ExtentSize->None,
Filling->None]
```

Uses the code from the question to the linked answer, copied for convenience:

```
ClearAll[T, z, Pr, D1, D2, XX];
x = 10^-4; y = 10^4; n2 = 2; alpha = 2;
W1 = Sqrt[n2^2 - z^2];
W2 = Sqrt[z^2 - n2^2];
Pr = ((alpha - 1) (x y)^(alpha - 1))/(y^(alpha - 1) - x^(alpha - 1));
D1[T_, p_] := Pr*p*Exp[(-z)*T]*(Cos[T*W1]/z^2 + (1/(z*W1))*Sin[T*W1]);
D2[T_, p_] := Pr*Exp[-z T] (p*Cosh[T W2]/z^2 + 1/(z W2) Sinh[T W2]);
XX[T_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] :=
NIntegrate[D1[T, p], {z, x, n2}] + NIntegrate[D2[T, p], {z, n2, y}];
```

Which produces the plot:

[image: Image from linked SE post with original DicretePlot3D answer]

Which, though it lacks any adjustments to the plotting style, these are possible to change.
However, what is does lack, which is not possible to change, is a simple way to add a meshing to the plotted surface. Requesting `Mesh->True`, one is reminded that `Mesh` is not an option for `DiscretePlot3D`.

We can clearly see our desired output by looking at user Nasser's plot, which uses `ListPlot3D`:

[image: Nasser's Plot from linked Question]

And so, my question is simple:

## How can meshing be implemented in `DiscretePlot3D`?

Comment: Have you tried to plot the meshlines simply with `ParametricPlot3D`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher you could do that using the function example here? Then using `Show` to combine them? I’m not exactly sure how I would plot the meshlines using `ParametricPlot3D`, can you provide an example?

Comment: Well, you have a parameterization of the surface, right? So can draw the mesh lines by just running one of the parameters while fixing the other one.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I’m a bit self-learned so let me ask for clarification: so, the surface is parameterized because I can compute it with two parameters, which give me the third parameter. Then, I can draw **real** mesh lines with `ParametricPlot3D` by fixing some parameter and running the other? I ask this as the method would likely be more self contained and automated. Or I can essentially make my own meshing function for this `DiscretePlot3D` method, by just plotting some lines as my mesh based on the level of discretization?

Comment: Yeah, you just draw you own lines and display everything together with `Show`.